# Fail to reload module res_odbc.so in Asterisk server

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, odbc

I configure my `/etc/asterisk/modules.conf` file with the following code:

```
[modules]
autoload=yes
preload => res_odbc.so
preload => res_config_odbc.so
```

After that, I went back the CLI console to reload the `res_odbc.so`. But it failed to find the `res_odbc.so`.

[image: CLI screenshot]

So how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have res_odbc.so in your modules folder.

To install `res_odbc.so`, you could install res_odbc dependencies and [make menuselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835551/how-can-i-load-res-odbc-so).

If you don't need ODBC, then
comment the preloading directive out.

In /etc/asterisk/modules.conf :

```
[modules]
autoload=yes
;preload => res_odbc.so
;preload => res_config_odbc.so
```